# pymongo query makes my flask server stop running

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

There's this route in my code which receives a .csv file and reads it. i'm pasting the entire route here. When lines 811-819 are commented, everything runs smoothly. However, when they are not, the loop executes and the execution of the program stops, i.e., the terminal shows:

```
david@david:~/tcgp$
```

here's the route:

```
@app.route("/uploadhc", methods=['GET','POST'])
def uploadhc():
    n,c,con,q,p=0,1,2,3,4
try:
    file = request.files['file']
    csv_f = csv.reader(file)
    data = [row for row in csv_f]

    for t in range(1,10):
        try:
            name=data[t][n]

            sets=translate((data[t][c]).lower())

            if data[t][con]=='':
                state='nm'
            else:
                state=data[t][con].lower()

            if data[t][q]!=666:
                quantity=int(data[t][q])
            else:
                quantity=1

            price=str(data[t][p])

            print name, state, quantity, price
          ############# line 811
            try:    
                items=CARDS_COLLECTION.find({'functionalname': name.lower()},{"_id":1})
                cardid=j['_id']

                for elem in items:
                    cardid=str(elem['_id'])
            except:
                cardid='3'
                print 'error'   
           ############### line 819

            print name, state, quantity, price

        except:
            print 'excpt'

    return ('',204)
except Exception as e:
    print '3'
    print str(e)
    return ('',204)
```

furthermore, if those two lines are commented:

```
for elem in items:
    cardid=str(elem['_id'])
```

the server no longer stops running when this route is called.

i'm absolutely clueless, since i use this same method of getting the data from my database in several parts of my code

edit: to make it even weirder, that line cardid=str(elem['_id']) seems to succeed in assigning the desired value to the variable cardid. only when the entire loop is finished, the server stops running.

edit2: nothing comes out of that except in line ~817, and if i add cardid to line 820 (print name, etc...), the cardid does get printed

Comment: Could you double check your indentation; for example line 4 looks incorrect.

Comment: i get no indentation error whatsoever. if you look at this print screen: https://imgur.com/12g6eiw , the error comes when i replace line 802 for 803
@belly-buster

Comment: OK - it's just the indentation above is different to the screen image. Was a quick one to rule out.